# Search by SKU get all products

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento-search

After we upgraded to 2.4.5-p1, our search engine stopped working when someone searches for a product by its SKU.

After some debugging, I noticed that when the SKU is 9 characters or longer, Magento tries to fetch all the products from our large database, which contains over 2 million products, and then only shows the product with the exact SKU.

We are experiencing this issue specifically when searching by SKU

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by incorrect configuration or a possible bug in the Magento search engine. Here are some suggestions to troubleshoot the problem:

Check search settings: Access the Magento admin panel and go to "Stores" > "Configuration" > "Catalog" > "Catalog Search". Verify the settings related to SKU search and ensure they are properly configured. Make sure the SKU field is selected as a searchable attribute.

Reindex data: Reindexing is an important step after upgrading Magento or making any changes to the catalog. Make sure to reindex all relevant indexes, including "Product Attributes" and "Catalog Search". This can be done by accessing the Magento admin panel and going to "System" > "Index Management".